# How can i open json files in folder and read them or print them in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

i want to iterate and check if a new files are updates in the folder then read the files e.g. data.json then access the data and print them . but I cant seem to access the data inside the file it self

error message:with open(json_files) as file:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

```py
import os, json
import pandas as pd

path_to_json = '/Webservertesting/JsonFiles'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')] #creats a lis of the files in folder
print(type(json_files))  # for me this prints ['foo.json']

for jsonfile in json_files:
    print(jsonfile)
    with open(jsonfile,json) as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            print(data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Read several json files from a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539679/python-read-several-json-files-from-a-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for jsonfile in json_files:
    print(jsonfile)
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, jsonfile)) as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            print(data)
```